# xml parsing in python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

my xml code fetched over network looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?><liverequestresponse><liverequesttime>180</liverequesttime><livemessage></livemessage></liverequestresponse>
```

and my python minidom code is

```
import urllib, urllib2, time
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read() 
#print the_page 
dom = parse(response)
name = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS('liverequestresponse')
print name[0].nodeValue
```

gives some errors

```
print the_page
```

works fine

Or if they are any other libraries which are better than minidom, plz tell me..
I would prefer the one which comes pre-installed on linux

**UPDATE**

*errors*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logout.py", line 18, in <module>
    dom = parse(response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1920, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 928, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 211, in parseFile
    parser.Parse("", True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `response.read` before `parse(response)` you'll already have read the content of the response. a second call to `response.read` (which `parse` is doing) will result in an empty string.

The simplest solution is to just drop the first `response.read` call. But if you really need the response string for some reason, you could try:

```
import urllib, urllib2, time
import StringIO
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read() 
#print the_page 
dom = parse(StringIO.StringIO(the_page))
name = dom.getElementsByTagName('liverequesttime')
text = name[0].firstChild
print text.nodeValue
```

Comment: it prints none!, I tried dropping response.read too.. its not that important so I commented it and run the script the outout was none

Comment: it prints `None` because the `liverequestresponse` node has no value. It only contains a child node, which contains a text node which has a value. `minidom` isn't the most userfriendly xml parsing library. `lxml` is way better, or also `xml.etree` is nicer.

Comment: That worked, I tried with `childnode` but it didnt worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An approach with [lxml](http://lxml.de/), which is being very used in Python lately to parse XML with very good results and performance:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

with urllib2.urlopen(req) as f:
    xml = etree.parse(f)

xml.find('.//liverequesttime').text
```

The output of the last line would be: `180`

Comment: lxml has to be installed are there any inbuilt libraries which are better than minidom?

Comment: lxml needs to be installed but it is pre-packaged on a lot of linux distributions, though you always can install it with `easy_install`

Comment: I dont want to take the chances I'm writing a http login client for minimalistic linux, I may have to use this on Arch linux core

Comment: Well, it seems you have it available with [Arch linux](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=lxml&maintainer=&last_update=&flagged=&limit=50) in extra repository

Comment: it is in the repos but my script logs in to a server on intranet after which I can access internet

Comment: As I said before, you always can install `lxml` with `easy_install` and this library really outperforms minidom and is more pythonic.

Comment: ya its better than minidom but the point is my situations are different any way thanx for the answer I'll use lxml when I have to